# What is the exact meaning of this phrase in D3.js Path Transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jqplot

In going through the documents of making line charts using D3.js I came across this page from the maker of D3.js.
In this [article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) he explains how to make a moving line chart in D3.js, and somewhere in the middle of the article he mentions this:

> The old path had three control points, and the new path has three control points, so the naïve approach is to interpolate each control point from the old to the new:
>
> ⟨0,0⟩ ↦ ⟨0,6⟩
>
> ⟨1,6⟩ ↦ ⟨1,4⟩
>
> ⟨2,4⟩ ↦ ⟨2,5⟩
>
> Since only the y-values change, this interpretation results in a vertical wiggle. When you tell D3 to transition between two paths, it takes exactly this simple approach: it finds numbers embedded in the associated path data strings, pairs them in order, and interpolates. Thus, the transition interpolates six numbers (for the three control points) and produces the same wiggle.
>
> To eliminate the wiggle, interpolate the transform rather than the path. This makes sense if you think of the chart as visualizing a function—its value isn’t changing, we’re just showing a different part of the domain. By sliding the visible window at the same rate that new data arrives, we can seamlessly display realtime data:"

What does he mean by *"interpolate the Transform, rather than the path"*?

if the x-axis values are the same for consequtive samples (which can happen if x-axis values are moving in milliseconds, but we need to send across only "minutes.seconds", how can we remove the vertical wiggle?

I ask because I am facing this same issue in another toolkit (jqplot), and here ticks need to be shown in "minutes.seconds", but x-axis data is being sampled in milliseconds so while converting them to "minutes.seconds" mutliple xaxis points are created with different y-axis values, and as the data is "shifted" from left side, I see a jagged vertical wiggle in my chart.

Can anyone explain please how to get rid of this multiple y-axis values against same x-axis value limitation.

Answer (score 2):

The article contains the answer to your question. It provides code to demonstrate the described behaviour:

```
// redraw the line, and then slide it to the left
path
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null)
  .transition()
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ")");
```

This code snippet applies the transition to the transform attribute of the svg line element. Another approach would be to apply the transition to the line itself (as staded earlier in the text):

```
// transition the line
path.transition().attr("d", line);
```

The first code snippet moves the entire line in the x direction, whereas the second code snippet moves the points that the line consists of into the y direction (via the line() function.